# What are the masks and droids in "The Mandalorian" intro?

Tags: star-wars, reference, the-mandalorian

*The Mandalorian* intro shows a set of masks and droids that are famous throughout the *Star Wars* universe.

I've recognized a few, but not all. In order,

- Darth Vader, R2-D2, C-3PO​ (unsure)
- ?, R2-D2 (again?) and some sort of rebel fighter?
- Kylo Ren and the Mandalorian

What are the masks/droids shown in the intro?

Comment: For clarification, I think what you are seeing is Disney's Star Wars vanity card; I think this will be used for any Star Wars universe production moving forward (I am not sure if it has been used elsewhere already).  I'd consider akin to the Marvel Studios vanity card that leads Marvel movies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The order the droids and helmets are or belong to:

1. Darth Vader
2. BB-8
3. C3PO
4. Kylo Ren
5. R2D2
6. A Rebel Pilot
7. A stormtrooper
8. The Mandalorian

From [CBR](https://www.cbr.com/the-mandalorian-star-wars-new-fanfare/),

> The first image is of perhaps the single most iconic character from the entire series, the Sith Lord Darth Vader. The pictures change though, to snapshots of various other characters. Next, are a number of major droids who have assisted in the battles against the Dark Side (namely R2-D2, C-3PO and BB-8). They are illuminated with a soft blue light. The red light next illuminates Kylo Ren's helmet from when it first appeared in The Force Awakens. The red light also extends over what appears to be the Empire equivalent of a protocol droid.
>
> A Rebel pilot and a First Order stormtrooper can be seen with the next blue flash. Meanwhile, one final red flash illuminates the helmet of the Mandalorian.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to AJ's answer—I think the 7th is a [scout trooper](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Scout_trooper), the 8th is a first order stormtrooper.

Answer (score 1):

The order the droids and helmets are or belong to:

1. Darth Vader
2. BB-8
3. C3PO
4. Kylo Ren
5. R2D2
6. A Resistance pilot - perhaps Poe
7. Scout trooper
8. An stormtrooper - Captain Phasma
9. The Mandalorian